# Xamarin iOS open sqlite file SQLite.SQLiteException: 'file is not a database'

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am working in Xamarin Forms with an iOS app.
The code downloaded successfully an sqlite file and I moved the file to the following location:
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/787D3CB8-01E1-41BB-B786-972534E7F563/Documents/Data/**test-file.sqlite**

but now when I try to open it with the following code I get a strange error:
**SQLite.SQLiteException: 'file is not a database'**

The database is also not encrypted

here is my code:

```
var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(_dbPath);
var versionlist = await db.QueryAsync<version_history>("SELECT * FROM version_history ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
```

after I do the QueryAsync I get the error, the file is not a database.
but the db object does have the information
[image]

Please help me, any ideas?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=sqlite+"file+is+not+a+database"+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: It has been some time but I found and fixed the problem. So here is the funny thing. It turned out it wasn't a real sqlite file after all. It was a zip file but named as a sqlite file and the more crazy is, the fact that it was readable by the sql lite lib. Even when it was a stil a zip file

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please post your comment to answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it wasn't a real sqlite file after all. It was a zip file but named as a sqlite file and the more crazy is, the fact that it was readable by the sql lite lib, when using SQLiteAsyncConnection.
Even when it was a zip file.
But the moment you fire a query, you will get the error saying that it is not a database.